# Мониторинг игрового сервера

Tags: php, сервер, библиотеки, мониторинг

Нужен простой скрипт php скрипт для вывода информации с игрового сервера типа:

Сервер: 46.38.56.3:27015

Название: Army Ranks 1.3

Карта: cs_assault

Игроков: 19/24

Статус: On-line

В интернете куча есть но я не понимаю что в них не так прописано так как все они не выводят информацию (
Может кто помочь? 
п.с. только мне для другой игры. тоже их valve

```html
<?php

$server = '46.38.56.3';
$port   = '27015';

function GetServerInfo($server,$port) { 
     $fp = @fsockopen("udp://".$server, $port); 
     if (!$fp) return false;

     @fwrite($fp,"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x54\x53\x6F\x75\x72\x63\x65\x20\x45\x6E\x67\x69\x6E\x65\x20\x51\x75\x65\x72\x79\x00".chr(10)); 
     $start=time(); 
     socket_set_timeout($fp,1); 
     $st=fread($fp,1); 
     $r=socket_get_status($fp); 
     $result['status'] = $r["timed_out"];
     $r=$r["unread_bytes"]; 
     if ($r == 0) { @fclose($fp); return false;} 
     $st.=fread($fp,$r); 
     @fclose($fp);

     $st=substr($st,5); 
     $address=SubStr($st,0,StrPos($st,chr(0))); 
     $address=str_replace(chr(0),"|",$address); 
     $st=SubStr($st,StrPos($st,chr(0))+1); 
     $name=SubStr($st,0,StrPos($st,chr(0))); 
     $st=SubStr($st,StrPos($st,chr(0))+1); 
     $map=SubStr($st,0,StrPos($st,chr(0))); 
     $st=SubStr($st,StrPos($st,chr(0))+1); 
     $st=SubStr($st,StrPos($st,chr(0))+1); 
     $st=SubStr($st,StrPos($st,chr(0))+1); 
     $current=ord(SubStr($st,0,1)); 
     $max=ord(SubStr($st,1,1));

     if ($map == "") return false; 
     $result['map'] = $map; 
     $result['name']= $name; 
     $result['current'] = $current; 
     $result['max'] = $max;

     return $result; 
}

$serv = GetServerInfo($server,$port);

if ($serv) {
echo '
Сервер: '.$server.':'.$port.'
<br>
Название: '.$serv['name'].'
<br>
Карта: '.$serv['map'].'
<br>
Игроков: '.$serv['current'].'/'.$serv['max'].'
<br>
Статус: On-line
';
} else {
echo 'Статус: Off-line';
}

?>
```

Comment: тут по вашему сообщению тоже мало кто понял что-либо. Если вы используете готовый продукт, то ищите на форумах поддержки. Если вы пишите свой скрипт, то выкладывайте код, ссылки на API сервера, и рассказывайте что у вас не получается.

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации, добавьте описание конкретных проблем, с которыми вы столкнулись.

Comment: Обновил пост. Вот конкретно этот код не работает на сервера которые там прописаны.

Comment: После `if ($serv) {` напиши `echo var_dump($serv);` и посмотрите что вам приходит, в соответствии с этим выводите нужные параметры `$serv['<PARAMETER_NAME>']`

Answer (score 0):

У вас `GetServerInfo` возвращает `false`, т.к. `if (!$fp) return false;`

Comment: Просто убрать ?

Comment: @МаксимЛысак зачем?